Fantasy film. Man killed in car crash becomes dream-world monster
There was a movie on Netflix several years ago that I'm trying to find.
The movie begins with a man who I believe blows an important meeting and as he is angrily beating his steering wheel he's hit by a car and killed. 
The movie has him depicted as a ugly monster man attacking a sleeping house and several people pop out of the air and fight him inside.
He kidnaps a girl and maybe another person then escapes. The woman tries to talk to him as he travels through back hallways and you realize he is the man from the beginning. 
There is something to do with time being very flexible and I think he ends up saving the people he has hurt. 
I'm fairly sure the title is a single word.
